# I have a problem with RichTextBox in winform C#

Tags: c#, richtextbox, copy-paste

I have a program where I use a UserControl I made myself with a RichTextBox.
In code I open a new tab in tabcontrol and adds my usercontrol.

But I in one tab select some text(ctrl-c) and go to another tab and paste it(ctrl-v), the selected text dissapear from the first tab.

If I do it in the same tab with ctrl-c and ctrl-v, it works okay.

Its only from one tab to another that ctrl-c works like ctrl-x

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I found out it was not the ctrl-c command that gave me problems.
If I just selected a text in one tab and go to another tab, the selected text would be deleted.

I fixed it by adding a DeleteAll() command to my user control.

Comment: I cannot do that for two days.